# Getting different spectrum from velocity, and position data using Omega arithmetic

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum

I am solving a very long problem and one part of it requires me solving an ODE and computing FFT of the resultant data. Essentially I have a differential equation$\frac{dz}{dt}$ for velocity, from which I can derive the acceleration equation. I can then solve the ODE and input the values in the acceleration equation and perform Fourier Transform, or I can take FT of velocity data and multiply it by $\omega$, or I can directly perform FFT on $z$ and multiply the output by $\omega^2$. All these three methods should produce similar spectra.

However, I am getting completely different spectra using these three approaches. I am posting what I think is the relevant part of the code(pertaining to FFT)and the relevant plots. I am not adding complete code to avoid cluttering and possible distraction from the main issue. If someone needs more explanation let me know.

PS: $\beta$ and $\tilde b$ are just two parameters in my ODE. The peak frequency depends inversely on $\tilde b$

**Plots**:
[image]
[image]
[image]

As requested in the comment section, I am adding the plot of position, velocity, and acceleration in the time domain.
[image]
[image]
[image]
Here is the relevant code snippet.

```
 '''
Fourier Transformation of the acceleration
'''
#https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15770-scaling-the-fft-and-the-ifft

fft_scaling_factor = 1
spectrum_acc =[]
spectrum_vel =[]
spectrum_pos =[]
velocitylist =[.24]
impact_parameter = [0.01,0.1]

for index,b in enumerate(impact_parameter):
    filter_coeff =[]
    spectrum_a =[]
    spectrum_v =[]
    spectrum_z =[]


    for j in range(len(velocitylist)):
        fft_scaling_factor = 1
        filtered_acc =[]
        filtered_vel =[]
        filtered_pos =[]

        fft_input_acc = acc_normalized[index][j]
        fft_input_vel = velocity_normalized[index][j]
        fft_input_pos = z_list[index][j]

        fft_input_acc = detrend(fft_input_acc,type = 'constant')
        fft_input_vel = detrend(fft_input_vel,type = 'constant')
        fft_input_pos = detrend(fft_input_pos,type = 'constant')



        ft_acc_normalized = rfft(fft_input_acc)*fft_scaling_factor
        ft_vel_normalized = rfft(fft_input_vel)*fft_scaling_factor
        ft_pos_normalized = rfft(fft_input_pos)*fft_scaling_factor

        ft_acc_normalized = np.abs(ft_acc_normalized)**2
        ft_vel_normalized = np.abs([a*b for a,b in zip(ft_vel_normalized,freq_normalized)])**2
        ft_pos_normalized = np.abs([a*b**2 for a,b in zip(ft_pos_normalized,freq_normalized)])**2


        spectrum_a.append(ft_acc_normalized)
        spectrum_v.append(ft_vel_normalized)
        spectrum_z.append(ft_pos_normalized)


    spectrum_acc.append(spectrum_a)
    spectrum_vel.append(spectrum_v)
    spectrum_pos.append(spectrum_z)
```

Comment: For me it is not clear where you do your multiplications with $\omega$. Also, the FFT of MATLAB has the 0-frequency at its left, the Nyquist frequency in its middle and 2*Nyquist frequency at the right (which is equivalent to the DC component). This needs to be taken into account when multiplying by $\omega$.

Comment: I would expect, that if your acceleration spectrum is flat in frequency, then your velocity spectrum would *drop* as the frequency increases, not rise, and that the position spectrum would drop even faster.  Why is this not happening?  Or is that your question.  It further appears that this "omega arithmetic" is purely the invention of one guy, and is pretty much just the integration rule (i.e., $\mathcal{F}\left \lbrace \frac{d}{dt} x(t) \right \rbrace = \omega \mathcal{F}\left \lbrace x(t) \right \rbrace$), which is hardly new.

Comment: I deleted my answer to attract a better one and leaving my remaining question here: The description of your math required is correct but I don't quite see where you are multiplying by the frequency and frequency^2 in your code. Also you want to multiply the complex fft output by frequency and then take the PSD of that result; not clear to me that you are doing that?

Comment: Ok I follow now the multiplication by the frequency axis and your final power computation-- what are the units for frequency in the freq_normalized arrays?

Comment: @M529 I am using Numpy's rfft so the first frequency term is zero and the last is Nyquist frequency.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html

Comment: @DanBoschen freq_normalized is the frequency array generated from Numpy's rfftfreq function, which generates dimensionless frequencies.  
The default sampling frequency is one, so I am multiplying it by my sampling frequency and therefore the unit of frequency is radian per second.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfftfreq.html

Comment: That sounds correct to me- I was suspecting that you were possibly using a normalized frequency and that you didn't multiply by your sampling rate to put it in radians per second- but you confirmed you are doing that.  Could you plot the results of your raw data from your sensor without modifying (I assume from your description that you actually have validated acceleration, velocity and position data from your sensor). In comparison to the acceleration data, we should expect to see a 1/f and 1/f^2 relationship in the velocity and position data respectively. Have you confirmed that is true?

Comment: @TimWescott I don't have the velocity or position spectrum in my plot. I have plotted the power spectrum using acceleration, velocity, and position, using what you mentioned as the integration rule.
My problem is that all three plots are not the same, even though they should. I am doing all this for sanity check since the power spectrum from acceleration is different from what we expect from theory or analytic solution.

Comment: @DanBoschen Okay, I will update the question with plots of velocity and position and time domain. Just to be clear I don't have sensor data, I am using data obtained by solving a differential equation.

Comment: oh ok - I assume then you will just show the same type of results with the same error so no need unless those plots do appear as expected. Given you don't have that expected relationship then maybe the error is in your approach to the differential equation (which you don't show) that part may be best to post on the mathematics exchange site?

Comment: @DanBoschen Differential equation solutions are correct. They match theoretical predictions and also agree with the analytical solution(whenever we can find them). I didn't add them to minimize distractions.
The problem seems to lie in spectrum generation, but I can't pinpoint where. I used anti-aliasing filters as well but no luck. Maybe I need to use some filters but I have tried all available filters none gives me what I want.

Comment: Ok if your equations are correct then the spectrums without your modifications that you did here should have a 1/f and 1/f^2 relationship. Do they? If you integrate a waveform, it's spectrum will be roll-off by 1/f  with reference to the original waveform- so maybe just confirm all of your processing with a simplest case like that to pin-point your issue.

Comment: @DanBoschen When you say integrate a waveform does that mean I should integrate the Fourier transformed acceleration(or velocity or position) wrt to frequency? That will give me a single number. How do I compare that with oriignal waveform?

Comment: No integrate the time domain waveform wrt that contains many frequencies (white noise is one choice, or multiple tones at decade frequencies) and then compare the PSD of the integrated waveform to that of the original waveform. For example, integration of cos(wt) will give your 1/w sin(wt) which is a waveform not a single value as you would get with a definite integral over the entire waveform.

Comment: velocity vs position in your time domain plots does not visually appear correct? the velocity is the derivative of position but appears to decay faster than the slope is actually changing? In any event to summarize my suggestion: create a "acceleration" waveform consisting of the sum of three equal magnitude sinusoids with three different frequencies: at 0.1 rad/sec, 1 rad/sec and 10 rad/sec. Pass this waveform through your integration process to create velocity and then pass both through your FFT process to create your PSD. See if you get the expected 1/f roll-off in the velocity PSD.